# Displaying Bootstrap Modal From Code Behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have looked at a few questions on here that are having the same issue I am having, but I can not seem to resolve my issue.

I am wanting to display a modal in certain scenarios... So I will need to show/hide based on certain scenarios. This is what I have :

**ASP.NET**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="lockUser" runat="server" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>Warning</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Watch out! Your about to be locked out.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

function openModal() {
        $('#lockUser').modal('show');
    }
```

**C#**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"Pop", "openModal();", true);
```

I have the C# code in a click event, everything in the event fires except for the above line...

Maybe I a missing something really stupid

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use your browser's console. If you execute `openModal()` from there, does it run? Are there any client side error messages?

Comment: Do you have `<asp:ScriptManager>` tag in your aspx file?

Comment: Try placing it in update panel as if you are using more than one scripts in a page its more likely not to load. try it and let me know may be I can help you more.

Comment: @jmc would I wrap anything inside of the `<asp:ScriptManager>`?

Comment: no, just add a `<asp:ScriptManager>` tag. You need an instance of ScriptManager in order to use methods like `RegisterStartupScript`. Your code will compile successfully even if you have not added the tag. Another option you have is to use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` if you dont want to use the `<asp:ScriptManager>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is make sure that the `openModal()` method works. If it does, then move the script files (`bootstrap.min.js`, etc.) and functions from the  bottom of your page to inside `<head>..</head>`.